# Image Gallery with frontend upload

Tags: extensions, phocagallery

I'm currently evaluating the different gallery extensions and there are lots of them.

I'm looking for a simple gallery with:

- frontend upload of bulk images while you're creating an article
- automated thumbnail creation
- easy insert into content articles with editor button
- the normal gallery view with categories

Is there something in this direction or can I search for a long time?

I have looked into the following extensions, but none of them satisfied completely:

- Phoca Gallery
- Simple Image Gallery
- SIGE

At the moment, it feels like JCE or JCE in combination with an Image Gallery might be the best way.

Comment: It would be great, after you trial a few, if you would post a comprehensive answer that compares the galleries that you tried and stated why you eventually selected a particular gallery for your project.  This would be very valuable to researchers.

Comment: There are quite a few galleries with front-end management such as Droppics, RSGallery2, 6gallery, Ignite Gallery and JoomGallery.

Answer (score 4):

I went through a review of Gallery extensions a couple of years ago with similar requirements and loaded up Phoca, JoomGallerry to test but eventually settled on Ignite Gallery from NZ. Ignite can do the resizing on the client before the upload, using PLUP(?) and was intuitive to set up, support was quick, it had plenty of options but seemed clean and modern. Phoca and JoomGallery have been around a long time and felt a bit dated from memory.

Of what has already been mentioned, I don't recall looking at Droppics.

It would be nice to find a better way to categorise the extensions calling themselves Gallery Extensions as some were fully featured extensions that handle uploading, ACL, category management and presentation(eg. Ignite, JoomGallery, Phoca) and inserting to editors while others really just presented images in a customisable way like Simple Image Gallery, SIGE and a plethora of forgettable ones.

Terry